# infinity recursive stack in prolog

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have this piece of code :

```
end_sol_cell(Row,9):-
   not(findall(Value,pos_cell(Row,9,Value),[_])).
end_sol_cell(Row,Col):-
   not(findall(Value,pos_cell(Row,Col,Value),[_])),
   New_Col is Col + 1,
   end_sol_cell(Row,New_Col).

w :- end_sol_cell(1,1), end_sol_cell(2,1).
```

when I call "w" it get into infinity loop how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What does `pos_cell/3` do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it wont loop with a cut:

```
end_sol_cell(Row,9):- !, /* <<< here */
   not(findall(Value,pos_cell(Row,9,Value),[_])).
end_sol_cell(Row,Col):-
   not(findall(Value,pos_cell(Row,Col,Value),[_])),
   New_Col is Col + 1,
   end_sol_cell(Row,New_Col).
```

But I am not sure whether it is exactly what you want.

Bye